# Computing logistic regression on variables of different years?

Tags: r, logistic

I am very new to R and statistics in general, so it is likely I am adopting the wrong approach.

I have a large dataframe made of binary, character and numeric variables with n observations per year. As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
"Year" = c(2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2013,2013,2013),
"Firm" = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"),
"Revenue"= rnorm(12),
"Performance award" = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),
 "CEO duality" = c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

My objective is to check whether some variables (for example "Revenue" e "Performance award")
in Year T are associated with the dependent variable (e.g., "CEO duality") in Year T+1.

Therefore, i realized the logistic regression is the model used to do it. But first, as far as I understood, to lag the dependent variable I first need to make my dataframe a timeseries (right?).

I read in other questions that timeseries include one only observation per year... So, how should I approach my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the outcome is appropriately cleaned (i.e. CEO Duality corresponds to the correct set of features) you can use a mixed model

```r
library(lme4)
model = glmer(CEO.duality ~ . + (1+Year|Firm), data=df, family=binomial())
```

This models the log odds ratio for YEar and intercept for each firm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a doubt though. If i do like this, do not i bring every variable in t+1? I need only the dependent variable to be in t+1 and all the others in t.

Comment: @Ludovico I think that is correct.